# Specifying private dependencies for NodeJS in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a small NodeJS project that I want to deploy in Cloud Functions. Because this project uses Pubsub, I used the emulator in my local machine to simulate Pubsub and so I can test locally without deploying first. I followed the instructions on Functions Framework and Pubsub emulator from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#linux-macos).

This is how my folder is structured:

```
project-folder/
+|index.js
 |package.json
 |lib/
  +|mod_1.js
   |mod_2.js
   ...
   |mod_n.js
 |node_modules/
```

Where the `js` files in `lib` folder are my utility functions. I import these modules in the program's entry-point file `index.js` (as I am not too familiar with "standard" NodeJS dependency management) in local dev like this:

```
const mod_1 = require('./lib/mod_1');
const { mod_2a, mod_2b } = require('./lib/mod_2');
...
```

The `package.json` looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "functions-framework --port=3000 --target=app",
```

And I start my application using `npm start`, which pretty much works.

However, when I try to deploy to Cloud Functions using `gcloud functions deploy...` command in my shell, the deployment fails as it cannot find my private modules. So reading from documentation about specifying dependencies in Cloud Functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs), I updated the dependencies in my `package.json` to include my modules in `lib`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.5.1",
  "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.1.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  ...
  "mod_1": "file:./lib/mod_1",
  "mod_2": "file:./lib/mod_2",
  ...
},
```

But still fails to deploy due to the same issue and now with the added problem that I have error when I run my program locally as it cannot detect the modules. I tried various combinations in `index.js` and `package.json` like removing the `lib` prefix in `require`, adding a `.js`, etc, but none seems to work.

My question is:

(1) Is there a single, universal standard (folder naming, importing libraries, etc) for dependencies in NodeJS? It seems to me that different frameworks has different styles.

(2) How can I make the dependency work both in my local dev environment and when I deploy to Cloud Functions?

My NodeJS runtime is version 10 (at least for Cloud Functions).

Comment: This "private modules" are stored in your local machine? You'll need to publish somewhere accessible by the cloud function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js dependencies are other modules installed through NPM, your utility functions are not module dependencies. You don't need to add them to package.json. When you deploy your function all your source code will get packaged into a zip-file and uploaded. Here is a link to the correct guide you should be looking at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem

So remove the mod_1 and mod_2 lines from your package.json, and any other references you might in there that point directly to your own source code.

Comment: When I deploy the original setup, that works on my local machine, I'm getting error on Cloud Functions though, it can't detect the modules in `lib` folder.

Comment: Can you post your index.js